# Scrapy Shell: How to execute multiple lines of code in shell?

Tags: python, shell, scrapy, ipython

You will see in the screenshot that pressing enter after pasting a multiline code doesnt run it but merely send each time a "...".

How can I run this multiline pasted code?

someone asked [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/q_QJhSXJcXM), but did not get (the right) answer;

[image]

**Did not work:**

- Backspace
- Use the arrow key to move the cursor, then use the delete key
- Escape
- F2

Comment: Try using escape chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing enter twice when inside the Python interpreter executes a block of code, but you have an unmatched open parenthesis on the last line, so you haven't completed defining the block of code.  Also, I'm not sure what `dic` is in the last line, because you haven't included its definition, so you may need to fix that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
 a=[1,2]
 for x in a:
     print(x)
```

actually works (pressing 2 enters worked as expected). So I made a mistake in the code above. I aplogise, I should have checked that before.

I don't delete the question since the one on google can be confusing (the guy did not mentioned it was his mistake, so I though there was a trick to be found. The trick is to check the code).

Answer (score 0):

you could use IPython [link](https://ipython.org/install.html) which simplifies the process, better yet you have access to every command line as if executed inside the shell.
The other alternative is to encapsulate this inside a function

Comment: Please take a look at the display of IPython, it's completely different from the one posted in the post, I'm sure by using IPython shell you won't have such problem

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a bit late, but someone will need the information sometime:
When you make a new line, i.e. title.quote.... you need to press the tab to create an indent, then it will work. Without indenting, you get the "expected an indent" error message.